# How to downgrade Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design from 10.6 to 10.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

Something upgraded my Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design to version 10.6.10617.1. This broke some EntityFramework code generators which use version 10.0 and if it's missing, they error out.

I uninstalled the EntityFramework June 2011 CTP and ran the following installers from a VS 2010 SP1 installation folder (after doing a remove): DACFramework_enu.msi, DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi, & TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi but the 10.6 version is still around.

What software upgrades Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design and how do I get back version 10.0 of  it, without doing a complete re-installation of  Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Visual Studio completely and cleaned the registry of everything related to Visual Studio and then reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not enough. You didn't reinstall ADO.NET EF Tools. EF Tools 4.2 CTP are intrusive = they break normal EF designer functionality and should not be installed on your main development machine. To fix your VS installation without reinstalling whole VS try to follow [uninstalling procedure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx) described in this article.